# Hibernate session overlap

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am using Hibernate to read/write data.

The situation is that I am having 2 processes cooperate on a record. Process A opens a Session, write a record to database in a transaction, then closes the session. After that, immediately, process B opens a Session and tries to read (in a transaction) the data written by process A.

The problem I am having is that process B read sometimes successfully the data just written by process A and sometimes process B cannot read the new record.

To overcome the problem, in process B, I try to close the transaction that tries to read data,  wait a second, open a new transaction, this time, data is fetched successfully!!! I really don't the solution.

Could you explain the situation?

Update 1: adding code

Code on process A:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Person p = new Person();
p.setID(1234);
p.setName("Truong Nguyen");
session.save(p);
tx.commit();
session.close();
//here is code to inform process B a data is added
//...
```

Code on process B: **NOTE: this code only execute after above code of process A is completely executed.**

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Person p = new Person();
p.setID(1234);
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
List results = session.createCriteria("com.sample.Person")
                      .add(Example.create(p))
                      .list();
log.debug("Result size: " + results.size());
tx.rollback();
```

Result sometimes is 0, sometimes is 1. But if I change code on process B as follow, it always returns 1.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Person p = new Person();
p.setID(1234);
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
List results = session.createCriteria("com.sample.Person")
                      .add(Example.create(p))
                      .list();
tx.rollback();

if (results.size() == 0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    results = session.createCriteria("com.sample.Person")
                     .add(Example.create(p))
                     .list();
    tx.rollback();
}
log.debug("Result size: " + results.size());
```

Comment: I would like to see the code where you flush Session A and create a new Session B. Also, why create two Sessions? Why not have the same session but two transactions?

Comment: 2 processes are 2 difference applications, so, 2 sessions are opened on two different apps

Comment: Do you create Process B's transaction before or after you flush and close the transaction from process A?

Comment: code on process B only execute after above code of process A is completely executed. Hence process B's transaction is created after transaction on process A is committed/flushed.

Comment: I've got to say that I've been reading over the hibernate docs all day. I think the problem isn't with hibernate, but with your database.

Comment: Thanks Nappa The Saiyan! I think it could be because of MySQL. Open/close session/transaction so quick might be a problem!

Comment: I meant: close session/transaction then open another one so quick might be a problem for MySQL!